# get_the_date echo +1 days

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display 1 day of published date from current post.

I have this code, but still display current post published date, not +1 day.

```
<?php $date = get_the_date(strtotime('j-F-Y, +1 days')); echo 'tomorrow '. $date; ?>
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I caused a misunderstanding with the **echo** that reads "**tomorrow**", what I mean by "tomorrow" is the next date of the post published date, not the "tomorrow" from today.

I changed my question here.
Example: I have some article that published 20-April-2020, I want to display the next date from the current published date in the bottom of the post content, that will display **21-April-2020**, and in all my posts published 21-April-2020 will display **22-April-2020**, and so do the other articles.

it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the date for the day after a post was published, you can use [`get_the_date`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) with a format of `'U'` to return a PHP timestamp, then use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get 1 day later and [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to output it in the format you require:

```
$date = date('j-F-Y', strtotime('+1 day', get_the_date('U')));
echo "tomorrow $date\n";
```

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your answer. But, I have edited my question

Comment: @DigitalFun see my edit. I think that should be what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get tomorrow at midnight timestamp with:

```
$tomorrow_timestamp = strtotime('tomorrow');
```

If you want to be able to do a variable amount of days you could easily do it like so:

```
$days = 4;
$x_num_days_timestamp = strtotime(date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+$days days")));
```

Or you can do it this way too:

```
$date = date('j-F-Y', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime(time()))); // 1-May-2020
```

`date` returns a string, whereas you want to be adding 86400 seconds to the timestamp. I think you're looking for this:

```
$date = date("j-F-Y", time() + 86400);
echo 'tomorrow '. $date;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your answer. But, I have edited my question

Comment: Just use i i proposed, this is what you need.